# CPU overheating. Never was overclocked

Tags: cpu, temperature, overheating, intel-core-i5

I have Intel Core i5 2500k. I used it for approx 2 years with Corsair H100 cooling system. 
I have been working in IT for past 10 years so I have excluded all the obvious: I have replaced cooling fan, reapplied thermal compound (couple of times), reset the bios, made sure that all parts of cooler are seated properly.

At the moment it is constantly on 70 degrees, even in IDLE, which is obviously to high.

My question is: can the processor get damaged after for example 2 years and start overheating? Or maybe it's fine, but the motherboard reports high temperature?

Have anyone seen this before?

Comment: Do you have an infrared spot thermometer so you can measure the surface temperature along the exposed edge?

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately I don't have one.

Comment: Try to use the stock Intel cooler to see if it is the problem of your heating sink

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

1. Something is broken with your CPU (or other hardware?) causing CPU to overheat.
2. The heat sensor has malfunctioned.
3. Could it somehow be a software problem e.g. virus (does the overheating occur during BIOS, with replacement HD and OS (e.g. linux on usb)).
4. I know you've reset your BIOS, but double check the settings.  70°C while not ideal is *not* too high for a CPU, maybe it's simply trying to keep the fan slow and quiet?  Alternatively maybe its tuned for the default fan not a H100.
5. Maybe the H100 has some characteristics you're not accounting for - does it have a pump and is it working etc.  No blockages?  Position correctly?  Consider using a stock cooler to rule out issues here.